# DIsplaying image retrieved by Ajax

Tags: ajax, image, http

I read a number of posts on this but nothing seemed to help. I have an ajax client that retrieves an image from a remote web service running on a Jetty server. If I use the browsers (Firefox etc.) the retrieval is displayed successfully. If I use the ajax script the image is displayed as a bunch of unreadable characters. Does the image need to be sent a certain way from the server in the ajax case? I have tried many different methods including data URI ones but nothing seems to work. Any ideas? I will greatly appreciated it. Thakns.

Answer (score 1):

Actually getting an image asyncronously is the literal way of doing it with javascript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://your img uri";
document.getElementById("image_container").appendChild(img);
```

No need for XHR type AJAX to get it.

If you need a success callback, you can add it before the `img.src` definition:

```
img.onload = function() { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

The X in AJAX stands for XML. So the result is basicly text.
You can change this, but depends on the framework used. Like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Maybe you are trying to do something that won't need AJAX.
Or you AJAX only retrieves the URL of that image.

If you have the IMG DOM Object already instanced in a var like:

```
var img = document.getElementById('my_img');
```

and you already have the image path (ie: '/img/img.jpg')

try

```
img.src='/img/img.jpg';
```

Comment: Good feedback thanks. However, I do need Ajax because nothing is written on the server side (I am dealing with mobile devices) and rather the data (image) resides in memory after it is snapped. I am using p2p technologies to route the requests since the mobile devices are behind NAT = therefore even if I saved the images on the server they would not be URL addressable. I saw a number of postings claiming that either converting the byte array I receive into base64 encoding would work:

Comment: Sorry the message got cut off before I was done - here are the statements I found online that claim to work with the responseText:

Comment: Ok [ENTER} in stackoverflow does not give you a new line - trying once again:     var responseImage =           document.createElement("responseImage");
    responseImage.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + xhr.responseText;
    newhtml2="><img src=\"\" id=\"responseImage\"/>";     
    document.getElementById('parenthtml').innerHTML=newhtml2
 I think the point made above that Ajax is asynchronous XML is indeed the aha here. Unlike RPC/SOAP calls that can return attachments Ajax is not built for anything other than XML comms. And saving the file on the client is a no no (Security issue) from Ajax

Comment: I found a number of postings that Ajax can actually transport binary data as long as it is encoded (byte by byte - which will make it ridiculously slow). Any other ideas you can suggest for my problem? I understand that Ajax is not suitable for such retrievals so if I cannot address a URL directly I guess the only other option would be to write java classes and abandon scripting? Thanks again. <br><br> On another note, how can one write well-formatted responses on stackoverflow? Is there a tutorial somewhere? Do I need to use mini formatting or just HTML? Thanks again